# want to execute curl from Javascript, but don't know how set authentication option

Tags: javascript, curl, zendesk

Want to create the ticket in zendesk, but the scenario like cannot install cUrl. So want to execute curl from JavaScript. But don't know how to set authentication option.

```
var curl = new Curl();

[url, data etc code]

curl.setOpt(Curl.option.URL, url);
curl.setOpt(Curl.option.POSTFIELDS, data);
curl.setOpt(Curl.option.VERBOSE, true);
```

here which option I need to set for authentication ?

Comment: Is there a reason you chose to use curl instead of ajax? I'm not an expert on this, but I'm pretty sure ajax is the conventional way of doing this; there's definitely more documentation for ajax in javascript than curl.

Comment: appreciated your curiosity and willingness to know more about this. actually need to use ZenDesk API. [ you can refer more on this at https://developer.zendesk.com/rest_api/docs/core/introduction ] which shows mostly cURL in their documentation. I tried a lot and even still trying to do the same using ajax. And curl is the another option, so tried, how to call curl from JavaScript. Because the scenario is, where I can only do the custom JavaScript/JQuery code.

Comment: I'm familiar with ZD's API. I guess what I'm trying to say is, although their documentation uses curl examples, you don't necessarily need to use curl to access their API. From my experience, I've only used curl via the command line (or when writing local scripts such as bash/ruby), and used ajax in javascript/jquery. You may want to search for examples of ajax requests using the ZD API.